# What is the best way to store the current git branch or tag inside a repository

Tags: git

I have project which gets deployed to multiple sites. I need a way to identify which branch or tag version is being run on the site. I know that if each site was a simple clone of the original repository I could run a git command or read a file out of the *.git* folder. The stumbling block is that the servers being used may not have shell access. Deployment to those sites will be downloading a zip file of the desired tag and then extracting it on the site.

So I was wondering if there is a way I could have GIT output the tag or branch *inside* the repository? That file would be automatically updated everytime a commit is done (or more correctly when a tag is created).

Comment: Just make it a part of your build-deploy process. Put a changeset id into a plain old text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can via [git](/questions/tagged/git) post-receive hooks to write out to a file. Once the commit/push is done, a command will automatically be executed to write out the current branch to a file.

```
As an example - In hooks/post-receive put the following

GIT_REPO=$HOME/myrepo.git

git branch | grep \* > current_branch.txt
```

If you require further detailed documentation - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: To clarify, I would put this on my origin repo, right? This would mean that when I push changes to it, it will generate the file locally on the server. Anyone who clones a specific tag would not receive that file. Maybe I'm not understanding the post-receive part.

Comment: Yep on your remote server. Essentially all post-receive hook is just a shell script that git automatically calls